# Dockerfiles organization

Tags: docker

Plenty of blog posts are available on the Internet and show how to write/optimize/use a Dockerfile but I didn't find very much about how to organize them.

My use case doesn't look exotic however: I have a Dockerfiles hierarchy, composed of base-Dockerfiles and plenty of child-Dockerfiles, all of them intended to be used to build images stored in an entreprise registry.

At first glance, putting them in a SCM (such as Git) sounds like a good idea. But a Dockerfile rarely comes singly. Most of the time there are extra configuration files (a SCM still perfectly fits) and possibly binaries (no longer fits).

Another option would be to store all Dockerfiles/configuration files/binaries on a host machine (why not the one that runs the private registry?) and make scheduled backups.

Does anyone has any feedback on this topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd definitely store the Docker files and the text configuration inside a SCM (e.g. git).
That's what they are made for (Source and Configuration Management)!

For the binaries, I've seen currently seen two approaches "in the wild":

- `wget <url>` inside the `Dockerfile`:

  - From a public URL (like the [Central repository](http://search.maven.org)
  - From a private binary artifact repository (see the [Sonatype Blog](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/04/what-is-a-repository/#.VH8L9cmTUv4) for an example.
- Using a shell script to copy the relevant artifacts to the Docker build directory.
  The shell scripts then invokes `docker build` inside that directory to actually build the image.

Other things that are possible are [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#import) (also see [Creating a Base Image](https://docs.docker.com/articles/baseimages/)) and [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#import), but these aren't likely to be relevant during day-to-day usage.

Comment: Thanks for these links. Using an artifact repository sounds like a good idea to me. By shell script, you meant a shell script executed before the "docker build" command, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I updated the answer to clarify this aspect.